# Issue With Network Activity Indicator Placement

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an application that retrieves an `XML` file, parses it, and then displays the data inside of a `UITableView`. When the application loads all is well. When you tap another tab in the `tabViewController` it pauses for a moment and loads the next view. I need the `NetworkActivityIndicator` to start animating when this takes place but I'm having some trouble with where to place the code for it.

I have tried placing it in the `viewDidLoad` method before anything else starts happening but the result is the activity indicator starts animating after the view has already fully loaded. If I place an `NSLog` statement in the same position it appears in the debugger console immediately when the tab is tapped. Why isn't the activity indicator animating immediately as well? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're loading the file on the main thread. The run loop only does UI changes on each loop, so if you freeze the main thread while loading nothing will change until it's done. You should consider doing the loading asynchronously...

A slightly hacky way to get around this is to perform a loop right after setting the network indicator visible:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1]];
```