# NSURLSessionDataTask and handler block

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I'm developing a library that gets `json` data from a server, and I'm using `NSURLSessionDataTask`. In order to test my library I created a new project that calls this library method.

```
typedef void (^CompletionBlock)();
// More stuff...
- (void)downloadAllPodcastsMetadataWithCompletionHandler:(CompletionBlock)block{

   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"MyServerURL"];

   NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
     // Connection and response handling stuff...
     // When my data is saved, executes the block parameter

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        block();
     });
   }
   [dataTask resume];
}
```

**EDIT:** I forgot to put [dataTask resume] here, but it's in my code. Sorry.

**EDIT 2:** So, as some of you have said, i changed dispatch_sync with dispatch_async. But the result is the same :(

In my test project i call this method like this.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

[manager downloadAllPodcastsMetadataWithCompletionHandler:^{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}];
```

But the network activity Indicator never shows off. It's like the block parameter never executes.

It's because it executes the `NSURLSessionDataTask` logic inside a library and then I should use something else instead `dispatch_sync`?

I already checked [NSURLSessionDataTask not executing the completion handler block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368651/nsurlsessiondatatask-not-executing-the-completion-handler-block) and I think I do the same. If it helps, **manager is a Singleton**.  Any thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: I wrote a class that can help you: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch24p842downloader/ch37p1099downloader/MyDownloader.m

Comment: Never use `dispatch_sync` unless you know exactly what you are doing. You are blocking yourself here!

Comment: Wow, thanks for that class. I'll check it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i'm dumb.

There was an error in my previous code i didn't notice, so the completion block war never executing. That is what happens when someone has too much confidence in his code.

Sorry for bothering you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the download with `[dataTask resume];`.

Comment: I forgot to add [dataTask resume]; in the question, but no in my code. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [dataTask resume]; and also  add this in completion handler
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
              });

Comment: I forgot to add [dataTask resume]; in the question, but no in my code. Sorry. I put [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO; inside the block parameter that receives the method. I dis it this way because it is a library, no a app, so this way can be use in many apps.

Answer (score 0):

I tested some code.

Dispatch_sync won't work.

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
});
```

Dispatch_async worked for me. But I had to put the code on veiwWillAppear.
Not sure what's going to happen using it inside a block...

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
});
```

Comment: I changed, but the result it's the same.

Comment: Did you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586166/issue-with-network-activity-indicator-placement

Comment: Yes, sorry. But i think it can't help me :( I'm doing my test right after my teste app is launched. I don't have any view or viewcontroller created. Just showing the network indicator.